# How to load flash in Android?

Tags: android

HI, i want to load a flash file in my android application. Can any one guide me how to do?

Answer (score 2):

A flash file requires the Flash Player runtime to...well...run. The ability to run flash files is available to the Android platform in two forms.

1. **As a plugin that renders Flash content in the native Android web browser**(just like your browser on your desktop computer), or by utilizing the **Android UI webView API** and loading an HTML file with an embedded Flash file. In other words, create a webview in your Android application and load it with the remote or local URL of HTML file with the embedded flash content.  Essentially you are putting a stripped down version of the Android browser into your application to render the Flash file.
2. **Adobe AIR for Android**. You could rewrite your Android application into a Flex Mobile Application, if your application relies heavily on Flash, and then run it directly as and AIR application and just us the AIR API's to load it.

A quick search on Google will show you code examples on how to write the HTML file to embed the Flash file, and it will tell you how to us the Android API webview to load said HTML file.

Good luck, let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: can you solve this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532303/problem-to-load-swf-file-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You need Android 2.2 or later. It has built-in flash support.

Comment: can you solve this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532303/problem-to-load-swf-file-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Android 2.1 you just cant do it.
Flash is only available on Android 2.2, so you have to upgrade it first.

Comment: can you solve it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532303/problem-to-load-swf-file-in-android

Comment: do you think that to load swf file i need flsh player in android?