# Problem loading swf file in android

Tags: android, flash

I have a problem when I load interactive SWF file in android emulator. I use 2.3.1 AVD.

This is the code:

```
package com.androidpeople.view;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    public class WebViewExample extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            /*WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.androidpeople.com");

            webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());*/

            String html =
                "<object width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> <param name=\"movie\" value=\"file:///android_asset/FL.swf\"> <embed src=\"file:///android_asset/FL.swf\" width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> </embed> </object>";
                String mimeType = "text/html";
                String encoding = "utf-8";

            WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
            wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", html, mimeType, encoding,  "");
            wv.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());



        }
    }


package com.androidpeople.view;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.androidpeople.view"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".WebViewExample"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

Now the problem is that when I run the project, it will give one box at center right side 3D dimension like:

[image: this is the image]

I have also tried to change different-different SWF file but can't get proper solution.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Is your link correct, e.g. if you add an a tag linking to file:///android_asset/FL.swf, can you download the file?

Comment: @niky: Part of the reason why you have no answers is that you did not ask a question, other than "can anyone help me?".

Comment: ya its totaly correct and i have check it many time

Comment: do you want entire project with zip file?

Comment: @niky: [This article](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) might help you to tweak your question to attract answerers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", html, mimeType, encoding,  "");
```

with

```
wv.loadData(html, mimeType, encoding,  "");
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: i have the same problem with emulator i have done as you suggested but all i got is just the blue symbol in the above image has gone but unable to see the animation and all my code was correct i have posted the question here please help me!   

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308712/how-to-run-the-swf-file-in-android-emulator

Answer (score 3):

That's just because you need to install flash Player.
Download the apk from adobe website and install it on the emulator.

Comment: Does that work when you browse the web? are flash animations displayed?

Comment: ya. and also ,my flash developer generate one apk via Adobe-air and when they test in device it is working fine but when i am trying to do this way any interactive swf file i got problem to load in device. one more thing i want to tell you is that when i try to load non-interactive swf file it will work fine. but problem is raise here....

Comment: i think is there problem of action script version? becase i have use actiion script 3.0

Comment: is there any caution by suggest you to chose swf file(caution in meaning of size r else)?

Answer (score 0):

Flash cannot run on the emulator!
At least, I did not find a way to do so. But, you can download an APK from [this site](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html#flash_player_archives) and install it on your device. Then, using the following code I got flash to work.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/");
}
```

In activity_main.xml:

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```