# HTML embeded in android

Tags: android, html

**i have try to load swf in android.i use this :**

[image]
**but,i think that  this is recommend to store SDCARD first and trying to display?**

[image]
my question is, my point of view is correct or wrong?
i have try by **android_asset** but not get success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you should use webview control to load SWF file. (if you have not done above).
Using webview, You can load swf file in any of following way,

1. Android Asset.
2. From SD Card.
3. URL from web.

Comment: can you solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532303/problem-to-load-swf-file-in-android

Comment: this has a problem because it does not have flash player.