# Android WebView - Flash swf plays, can hear audio, but screen is blank

Tags: android, flash

I am trying to display local flash swfs in the WebView. I have WebView set up and it will happily display local HTML files, but when I try to display Flash, the screen is blank. The flash file is running as I can hear the audio.

Any ideas, or is this just a known issue / bug? I have noticed that most swf players from the android market suffer the same issue.

Thanks,

Jon

Comment: your problem is like this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532303/problem-to-load-swf-file-in-android

Comment: it is also my post but still not getting proper out put. i have try since from 10 day.

Comment: niky, that isn't constructive. post your solution here, if you have one.

Comment: It doesn't work on Android 3.0+. On Android 2.2.*-2.3.*, the swf plays fine - video and sound.

Comment: Also, the flash reacts to touch and the swf stops/continues playing (sound only)

Comment: See this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383364/flash-video-not-displaying-in-webview-for-android-3-0-1

Answer (score 2):

In the manifest files set:
Set android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Source:
[Flash video not displaying in WebView for Android 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383364/flash-video-not-displaying-in-webview-for-android-3-0-1)